# SQL Join 2 tables and get respective answers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Here is my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac051a/1)

I have master table like

```
CREATE TABLE master (id int, name varchar(25), origin int, destination int);
INSERT INTO master (id, name, origin, destination) VALUES (1, 'Alpha', 1,2);
INSERT INTO master (id, name, origin, destination) VALUES (2, 'Beta', 3,4);
```

And airport table like

```
CREATE TABLE airport (id int, name varchar(25));
INSERT INTO airport (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Chennai');
INSERT INTO airport (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Delhi');
INSERT INTO airport (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Goa');
INSERT INTO airport (id, name) VALUES (4, 'Mumbai');
```

I tried using this sql query like

```
select master.id, master.name, master.origin,master.destination from  master
INNER JOIN airport ON master.origin=airport.id
```

But i am getting only this as answer

```
id  name    origin  destination
1   Alpha   1   2
2   Beta    3   4
```

How can i get like this

```
id  name    origin  destination
1   Alpha   Chennai Delhi
2   Beta    Goa     Mumbai
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two joins:

```
select m.id, m.name, ao.name as origin, ad.name as destination
from master m join
     airport ao 
     on m.origin = ao.id join
     airport ad
     on m.destination = ad.id;
```

Note the use of table aliases to distinguish between the two tables.  These also help make it easier to write and read queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query, hope you will get answer what you look for.

QUERY:

```
 SELECT master.id,
       master.name,
       master.destination                       AS destination,
       (SELECT airport.name
        FROM   airport
        WHERE  airport.id = master.origin)      AS origin,
       (SELECT .airport.name
        FROM   airport
        WHERE  airport.id = master.destination) AS destination
FROM   master
```